# Converting this summation into an integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

This summation includes a sum of *n* derivatives of the function `f(x)` at the point `(c+d) / 2`

I'm trying to convert a Taylor polynomial into an integral. Since I don't understand the MathExchange syntax, I have attached a couple pictures.

The first is the general problem:

[image]

The second is my conversion to a Taylor series summation:

(Sorry I left out that n goes from `0 to infinity`)

[image]

Now, how do I convert it into an integral?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your equation
in MathJax.

$$p(x)
=f\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)
+f'\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{c+d}{2}\right)
+f''\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{c+d}{2}\right)^2}{2}
$$

To use this
to get an error,
note that
on $(c, d)$
you have
$f(x)-p(x)
=f'''(z)\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{c+d}{2}\right)^3}{6}
$
or some error term like this.

You can then
write
$f(x)
= p(x)+\text{that error term}
$
and integrate $p(x)$
and get a bound
for the integral
of the error term.
That will give you
an approximation for the integral
(from $\int_c^d p(x) dx$)
and a bound for the error.